# Pipeline For Media Library for CD

Tags: media-library, pipelines, content-delivery

I'm new to Sitecore and I'm looking for the details of media library pipelines in CD. I'm trying to redirect media library link based on a flag. If the flag is checked for media library item then it should redirect to a page. We wont be able to depend on scheduled publishing since the number of media items is to huge(200-300 media items). So we need to publish the items and keep it as non accessible till the flag is un-checked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to hide media items from the public access?

Comment: Yes. I am, kind of embargo time functionality.

Comment: Media items are passing through the begin request pipeline.. why not just use that one?

Comment: We need this only for Media items.That's why

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to deal with pipelines for this, You can use Sitecore security restrictions to disable "**extranet\anonymous**" user access to these images, you can "deny" access of the containing folder of these Media items, and publish it, now the public will not have access to it until you give them access again.

[image]

More on Sitecore security can be found [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/assign_access_rights_to_a_security_account).

Comment: Okay. But authors will not have access to security editor. That’s why thought of using a flag.

Comment: @HarikrishnanN They don't need to access security editor for this, They can do this from content editor in the security tab->  Assign, As long as they author have "sitecore\Sitecore Client Securing" role

Comment: we have not provided any kind of access to Content authors for modifying the security.